# sqlite before delete insert trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to save the contents that are just about to get deleted from my Table1 to another identical table called Table2. All fields are identical in both tables. How is the trigger to look like ?

Comment: I hope this [link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) would help you answer your question.

Comment: @user3351050 While we like to help and answer questions, we don't like "questions" that sound like "do my work for me". In questions please include what you have tried, where you are stuck or why it didn't work, sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a trigger on Table1 (before delete - for each row) :

```
INSERT INTO [Table2]
    [VALUE1], 
    [VALUE2], 
    [VALUE3] 
  VALUES ([old].[VALUE1], [old].[VALUE2], [OLD].[VALUE3]);
```

Or you can use classic SQL :

> INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1;